# Error configuring Hibernate mySQL connection - Connection refused

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, model-view-controller

There are several questions with similar topics, but I did a thorough investigation and none of them could solve my problem.

I am working on a MVC Java project. I use Spring 3, Tomcat 8, MySQL 5 and Hibernate 4. I manually created a database, a table and a row. My Eclipse project can't access the database, despite everything seems to be in place and properly configured.

This is my base DAO:

```
public class BaseDAOImpl<ENTITY> implements BaseDAO<ENTITY> {

private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private Class<ENTITY> entityClass;

public BaseDAOImpl() {
    this.entityClass = (Class<ENTITY>) ((ParameterizedType)
              getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
}

// Other methods relying on the session //

@Override
public ENTITY createOrUpdate(ENTITY entity) {
    Session session = getSession();
    if (session==null) {
        //throw new ConnectException();
    }
    session.saveOrUpdate(entity);
    return null;
}
protected Session getSession() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        initializeSessionFactory();
    }
    return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
}

public void initializeSessionFactory() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
    StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
        .applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
    sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
}
}
```

And hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration SYSTEM 
"http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
       <property name="hibernate.dialect">
          org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">
          com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
          jdbc:mysql://localhost/sudomusic
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.port">
          3307
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.username">
          root
       </property>
       <property name="hibernate.connection.password">
          kk
       </property>

       <!-- List of XML mapping files -->
       <mapping class="com.evolusound.sudomusic.domain.Customer"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

So, when I try to save a new customer on the database, I get a JDBC Connection exception. The things that concern me the most are: am I creating the sessionFactory the right way in the DAO? Is there anything missing in hibernate.cfg.xml? It should map automatically my Customer.java with the Customer table, right? What I don't know is which link of the chain is missing, and it's obviously the connection, but I don't know at which step. Is it not properly configured or is something failing on first attempt? Any help will be much appreciated.

__

If it helps to shed some light, the Eclipse framework seems to be able to see the database with the Data Source Explorer using a mySQL connection. However, it can't see the table within it. I am sure the credentials are correct (root, kk) because I use them in the command line and in MySQL Workbench. Some help would be really appreciated.

__

Here is the console output:

```
[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Error calling Driver#connect] with root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:253)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:292)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2132)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:46)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:352)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:284)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverConnectionCreator.makeConnection(DriverConnectionCreator.java:55)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.BasicConnectionCreator.createConnection(BasicConnectionCreator.java:75)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:106)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
at com.evolusound.sudomusic.data_access.BaseDAOImpl.initializeSessionFactory(BaseDAOImpl.java:73)
...
AM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl stop
INFO: HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost/sudomusic]
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your port number correct? The default port for MySQL is 3306, but you have specified 3307 in your XML:

```
   <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost/sudomusic
   </property>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.port">
      3307
   </property>
```

Your problem is that you are trying to connect to MySQL on localhost:3306 but you are getting connection refused, possibly because MySQL is not running, or because the port is wrong.

Comment: The port is correct, and MySQL is running. I am connected using MySQL Workbench. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: Perhaps move the port configuration into the URL, rather than a separate property? <property name="hibernate.connection.url">
      jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/sudomusic
   </property>

Comment: That's not it either :( I tried it several times, with the same outcome

Comment: What's the output of "netstat -a"? I'm wondering if MySQL is only using named pipes and you need to enable TCP connectivity? MySQL workbench could be switching between them as required.

Comment: That output is too long to paste here. Can you ellaborate your idea?

Comment: I am not sure that MySQL is listening on port 3307 - it may be configured to use named pipes. If you run 'netstat -a' you can see if something is listening on port 3307. If not, you need to configure MySQL with a TCP listener.

Comment: I'm sure the port is correct. I can't remember why I changed the default one, but 3307 is still correct, as I can connect from MySQL Workbench using the same connection configuration: url (localhost), port, user and password. The things that concern me more are: am I creating the sessionFactory the right way in the DAO? Is there anything missing in hibernate.cfg.xml? It should map automatically my Customer.java with the Customer table, right? What I don't know is which link of the chain is missing, and it's obviously the connection, but IDK at which step.

Thanks again!

Comment: You need to confirm that MySQL is actually listening on port 3307, using netstat. You may have set the port in your configuration file somewhere, but if you haven't also configured it to be accessible over TCP, it will be ignored. MySQL workbench could be connecting over named pipes, which doesn't need TCP connectivity on port 3307.